# Portable SSD entering Emergency Mode

Tags: boot, ssd, portable

My portable SSD (WD My Passport 500gb) has Ubuntu and GRUB installed. On my own PC, it boots without problems. On any other pc, however it says "You are in emergency mode". I found 2 errors about `TPM Interrupt not working, using polling instead` and `Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/{my EFI partition's UUID}`. It refers to my ESP UUID, but in `grub.cfg` I set it to the Ext4's (/) UUID. DM me on discord `dutchslav` or reddit `u/dutchslav`.

Comment: Ubuntu default installs grub to internal drive. So with an external drive it will only work on same system you used to install. Very old bug with work arounds.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 You can create an ESP on external drive, edit fstab efi entry with the new UUID, and reinstall grub or copy /EFI/Boot & /EFI/Ubuntu from internal drive's ESP. For detailed help post report from this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair after creating ESP on external drive.